# Access to java debugger in-process

Tags: java, debugging

I'm writing some utilities to help me debug some tricky code.  In particular, I have a utility class which may be called to catch a breakpoint in response to dynamic conditions which can't easily be captured using conditional breakpoints.  The user must install the breakpoint in the class, which is no problem, but it's a bit annoying to then have to step out of the utility class to where I'm actually interested in debugging each time.

Is there any way to access the debugger from inside the debugged java process so as soon as the programmatic breakpoint catches I can put it at the relevant line?  Is there any interface to the debugger from inside the debugee process?

I have a BreakpointHere class with a breakpoint() method.  In this method there is a tight loop with this code:

```
        /* ||==\\   ||==\\   ||=====     //\\     ||   //     ||    ||  ||=====  ||==\\   ||=====  || ||
         * ||   \\  ||   \\  ||         //  \\    ||  //      ||    ||  ||       ||   \\  ||       || ||
         * ||   //  ||   //  ||        ||    ||   || //       ||    ||  ||       ||   //  ||       || ||
         * ||===    ||===    ||===     //====\\   ||//        ||====||  ||===    ||===    ||===    || ||
         * ||   \\  || \\    ||       //      \\  || \\       ||    ||  ||       || \\    ||       || ||
         * ||   ||  ||  \\   ||       ||      ||  ||  \\      ||    ||  ||       ||  \\   ||
         * ||===//  ||   \\  ||=====  ||      ||  ||   \\     ||    ||  ||=====  ||   \\  ||=====  () ()
         *
         * The user should set a breakpoint on the following line */
        /*         \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ \/ */
        /* >>>> */ stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(); // <<<< Yeah, right here.
        /*         /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ */
        // Good. If you're here, press step return now.
```

If the breakpoint() method is called and there is no breakpoint installed, the method prints a message telling the user that the program is paused, instructs them to install a breakpoint, and gives CLI options to ignore and proceed.  If a breakpoint is installed (prior to the method call or while it is paused), the breakpoint catches.

I would like to be able to then step return so that debug cursor is at the code that actually called BreakpointHere instead of requiring the developer to step return.

Comment: A code example always helps understand your use case, good luck

Comment: More info added